# Is there a way to set namespace scoped variables in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure, but I was wondering if it's possible to set namespace scoped variables.

```
(ns robot.core)

(def ^:dyanmic myar nil)

(defn somefunction []
   (binding [myvar 1]))

(defn -main []
  ((somefunction)
   (println myvar))
```

Running that will output `nil`, is there anyway to set namespace'd variables or will they need to be passed around to each function?

Comment: That is dangerous and not really recommended!

Comment: @Chiron, what is "dangerous"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[alter-var-root](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/alter-var-root) function allows you to change root binding of a variable:

```
(def ^:dyanmic *myvar* nil)

(defn somefunction []
  (alter-var-root #'*myvar* (constantly 1)))

(defn -main []
  (somefunction)
  (println *myvar*))
```

[binding](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/binding) function, on the other hand. allows you to run some code with redefined `^:dyanmic` variable without changing the core binding of it.

Comment: FYI: `^:dynamic` is what allows you to use binding to have a thread-local only visible value.  `alter-var-root` that you linked to explains that it actually does alter the var and is visible to all threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what are you trying to do but are you aware of :private metadata?

```
(def ^:private wohoo "wohoo")
```

And [defvar-](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.def/defvar-)?

I'm assuming that you want to hide your var from other namespaces.